# Binary Search Tree Deep copy and dereferencing

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, deep-copy

I'm trying to set up a deep copy constructor for a binary search tree but can't seem to figure out how to handle the dereferencing of pointers. I'm quite new to C++ and are starting to grasp how it all works, but this beats me.

Code is as below:

```
void copyTree_helper(Node **destination,const Node *source)
{
    {
        if(source == NULL)
        {
            (*destination) = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            (*destination) = new Node;
            (*destination)->data = source->data;
            copyTree_helper(&(*destination)->left, source->left);
            copyTree_helper(&(*destination)->right, source->right);
        }
    }
}

// Creates a binary tree by copying an existing tree
BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree &rhs)
{

    if(&rhs == nullptr)
        root = nullptr;
    else
        copyTree_helper(&(*root), &rhs);

    /*////////////////////////////////////////////
                 Needs implementation
    ////////////////////////////////////////////*/
}
```

The implementation of the binary search tree in the .h file looks like this.

```
struct Node
{
    // Data stored in this node of the tree
    std::string data;
    // The left branch of the tree
    Node *left = nullptr;
    // The right branch of the tree
    Node *right = nullptr;
};
```

Right now it won't compile with the following error messages:

```
BinarySearchTree.cpp:44:9: error: no matching function for call to 'copyTree_helper'
        copyTree_helper(&(*root), &rhs);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
BinarySearchTree.cpp:20:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Node *'
      to 'Node **' for 1st argument
void copyTree_helper(Node **destination,const Node *source)
```

Very grateful for any help or explanation that helps me figure it all out. 
Cheers!

Comment: The compiler error is pretty specific regarding the problem, which part of the error message confuses you?

Comment: @UnholySheep What confuses me is what to put in the function declaration to allow for a deep copy, as well as how to properly dereference in the function code.

Comment: Changing `copyTree_helper(&(*root), &rhs);` to `copyTree_helper(&root, &rhs);` should make it compile - although the preferred way in C++ would be to use "pass-by-reference" instead of passing "pointer-to-pointer"

Comment: And passing by reference would comply with it being a deep copy?

Comment: passing by reference allows you to modify the parameter with less "boilerplate" code - the behavior of the function is whatever you code it to be. As a sidenote `if(&rhs == nullptr)` can never be `true` without invoking *undefined behavior* - you cannot pass a `nullptr` to a `const` reference parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should pass `&root`, not `&*root` - `*root` is a `Node`, not a `Node*`.

This is much nicer to write functionally, though:

```
Node* copyTree_helper(const Node *source)
{
    if(source == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    Node* result = new Node;
    result->data = source->data;
    result->left = copyTree_helper(source->left);
    result->right = copyTree_helper(source->right);
    return result;
}

BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree &rhs)
    : root(copyTree_helper(rhs.root))
{
}
```

or, if you add a suitable constructor to `Node`:

```
Node* copyTree_helper(const Node *source)
{
    return source == nullptr
          ? nullptr
          : new Node(source->data, 
                     copyTree_helper(source->left), 
                     copyTree_helper(source->right));
}
```